# Use __attribute__((aligned())) in struct, why the result of sizeof is this?

Tags: c, memory-management

This is my test code:

```
#include <cstdio>
struct A {
    int  a;
    int  b;
    int  c __attribute__((aligned(4096)));
    int  d;
}t;
int main()
{
    printf("%d\n",sizeof(t));

    return  0;
}
```

The result is 8192, but I can't figure out the reason.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a few facts about alignment in structs that are worth mentioning:

1. The size of a type is always a multiple of its alignment.
2. The alignment of a struct is always a multiple of the alignment of all its members.

So, since one of these members has an alignment of 4096, the alignment of the struct itself is at least 4096. It will most likely be exactly that.

But since it needs a padding of 4080 bytes before `c`, the size of the struct is at least 4104, but it must be a multple of 4096, its alignment. So it grows to 8192.

Answer (score 4):

It's because `sizeof` tells where the next element in an array would be placed. That is if you have the declaration

```
struct A a[2];
```

You would need both `a[0].c` and `a[1].c` to be aligned at `4096` bytes.

Strictly speaking the compiler could manage to make this happen with a size of `4096`, but it doesn't probably because `struct A` will inherit the alignment requirement and put two `int`s before the `.c` field which too has to  be aligned which inserts `4080`ish bytes of padding between `.b` and `.c` and then `4080`ish bytes of padding after `.d`.

The way the compiler **could** have done this (without rearranging struct members) is to extend the concept of alignment. Instead of just having requirements that the address must fall on an address of the form `N*4096` it could extend this with an offset requiring it to fall on an adress of the form `N*4096-2*sizeof(int)`. Giving `struct A` such a requirement would result in that the `.c` element would naturally become `4096` bytes aligned without requiring padding between the `.b` and `.c` (too).

Comment: The compiler is *not* free to rearrange struct members as it pleases. The C standard requires that a pointer to `a` is also a pointer to the enclosing object, so the following is legal: `int* ptr = &t.a; ((struct A*)ptr)->b = 42;` As such, the compiler *cannot* manage to pack the given struct within 4096 bytes.

Comment: @cmaster Rearranging the members is not the only way to make it work with a size of `4096` bytes. The compiler might also require that the `struct A` would need to have an address `2*sizeof(int)` before a `4096` bytes boundary.